# How can I get a listview with links to assets?

Tags: android, html, listview, assets

I have the HTML files in assets named *n0.html*, *n1.html*, etc. I want to create a listview with links to these files, but I don't know how to do it.

I have such a decision with a raw folder. How should I change it to assets files?

```java
public class ViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.view);


        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        String itemname = "n" + bundle.getString("defStrID"); //getting string and forming resource name

        Context context = getBaseContext(); //getting context

        // Reading text file from resources by name
        String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(itemname, "raw", "ru.falcon5f.carguide;"));

        WebView wWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        String summary = "<!Doctype html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8></head><body>" + text + "</body></html>";
        wWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8"); //uploading text to webview
    }

    public static String readRawTextFile(Context ctx, int resId) // Reading text raw txt file
    {
        InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

        InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
        String line;
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return text.toString();
    }
}
```

---

**Added**

I'm sorry if I ask too stupid questions and I ask too much, but I want to work my first application. This is very important for me. So it consists of two activities:

**ViewActivity** which I've changed according to your advices

```java
public class ViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.view);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        String htmlFileName = "n" + bundle.getString("defStrID"); // Getting file name
        Context context = getBaseContext(); // Getting context. You still need that

        // Reading text file from resources by name
        try {
            String text = readAssetTextFile(context, htmlFileName);

            WebView wWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            String summary = "<!Doctype html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8></head><body>" + text + "</body></html>";
            wWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8"); // Uploading text to webview
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("TAG", e); // Note that you will need to import android.util.Log
        }
    }

    public static String readAssetTextFile(Context ctx, String fileName) throws IOException // Reading the HTML file from assets
    {
        InputStream inputStream = ctx.getAssets().open(fileName);

        InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
        String line;
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return text.toString();
    }
}
```

In `Log.e("TAG", e);`, [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) wants to change type of "e" to "String".

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not be that much different. You know that you can access a file in the assets like this:

```java
InputStream inputStream = ctx.getAssets().open(fileName);
```

You can place this instead of your line `InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);`. Then you need to pass in the correct file name. When working with assets you need not use IDs.

Editing your snippet:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.view);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    String htmlFileName = "n" + bundle.getString("defStrID") + ".html"; // Getting file name
    Context context = getBaseContext(); // Getting context. You still need that

    // Reading text file from resources by name
    try {
        String text = readAssetTextFile(context, htmlFileName);

        WebView wWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        String summary = "<!Doctype html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8></head><body>" + text + "</body></html>";
        wWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8"); // Uploading text to webview
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Exception thrown", e); // Note that you will need to import android.util.Log
    }
}

public static String readAssetTextFile(Context ctx, String fileName) // Reading HTML file from assets
{
     InputStream inputStream = ctx.getAssets().open(fileName);
     .....
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but how should I change this: Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        String itemname = "n" + bundle.getString("defStrID"); //getting string and forming resource name

        Context context = getBaseContext(); //getting context

        //reading text file from resources by name
        String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(itemname, "raw", "ru.falcon5f.carguide;"));

Comment: I have edited your snippet, hopefully this will make it easiest for you. I assume that you construct the html file name from the given bundle extra.

Comment: I guess so. Just try it out, I am not 100% percent what exactly comes into the activity through the bundle, after all you are the one implementing the application. If you face any problems or difficulties write back.

Comment: Please, look at the question. I've added problem which occurs when I added that code.

Comment: Oh, gosh I forgot this minor bit: `ctx.getAssets().open(fileName);` throws `IOException`. However your fix is not entirely correct - place all lines after `//reading text file from resources by name` in the method `onCreate` in the try/catch. Alternatively you can just assign text to null. Both will fix the Eclipse complaint.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid request, I am new in android coding, give an example in Listing please, or edit your answere if it's possible.

Comment: Done it. However keep in mind that the last changes interfere more with basic java knowledge and not with anything android specific.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work too. `Log.e("TAG", e);` Eclipse wants to change type of "e" to "String". Can I contact with you by email or other services?

Comment: I've added full code of application at the question. Please look.

Comment: Yeah sorry, yesterday I wrote an answer for you, but now it seems I forgot to post it. Regretfully you do not have enough rating for stackoverflow chat and I still will prefer to not use other communication services. As for your problem - again it is my mistake -  I confused the interface of the log function. Now I have fixed it in my snippet. I am sorry for the mistake.

Comment: There are no more errors, but when I'm clicking for example on First Topic in ListView there is unexpected error in application.

Comment: [Depositfiles](http://depositfiles.com/files/8bznvkm86) Sorry for depositfiles. Name of app `ru.stack`. Log made in aLogCat. Sorry I don't know how to use Adb.

Comment: The logcat is very explicit: ` android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {ru.stack/ru.stack.ViewActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml`. And the resolution: declare your activity in your android manifest:

Comment: It was very stupid of me. I have some projects in eclipse and I looked at another manifest. Now it works)) Thank you very much, you've done a lot for me. But when I opened html file there was a white screen only with top bar and app title. Here is logcat [link](http://depositfiles.com/files/clorzuf3s)

Comment: We are progressing: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: n1` - the file is not present. The reason being - I forgot that when you read from assets you need to pass in the extension too. I already corrected my answer once more. Try once more please. Also make sure n0.html and n1.html are present in your assets folder.

Comment: Yeah, it works. You have done a lot for me, thanks. Can I contact you via email if I have some small questions?

Comment: I would prefer not to be bothered via email for that. I will suggest you if you face some troubles first spend some time trying to fix the problem yourself. If this does not work formulate your question for Stackoverflow and go ahead. Here you will get faster and better answers than the ones I can provide.

Comment: Please, look this topic. You wrote a great peace of code and I think you can give me advice how to do that. Please. [back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403212/how-to-create-back-button-in-webview)